# How to change quaternion when flipping X axis?

Tags: unity, 3d, mathematics, animation, quaternion

For a given animation with the set of 3D coordinates of every joint and corresponding global rotations quaternions `Q(X, Y, Z, W)` in right-hand coordinates (Y-up, X-left, Z-forward) - pic. I want to change axis X to be consistent with Unity (Y-up, X-right, Z-forward).

[image]

For coordinates it is obvoius: `X' = -X` and works as expected.

For rotations in quaternions assign I probed different options from other sources:

- `X, -Y, -Z, W`
- `-X, Y, Z, W`
- `-X, Y, Z, -W`

So, what math behind flipping X axis and how can I achieve this transformation?

Comment: There are about 20 questions which are basically the same. I posted a solution i found works for me in this other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040325/unity-c-sharp-quaternion-swap-y-with-z-axis/74531976#74531976

I hope that helps others.

Answer (score 1):

`X, -Y, -Z, W` <-- This one is correct.

First you replace the axis you have (X) with the axis you want (-X), giving you:

`-X, Y, Z, W`

Then, since you've flipped an odd number of axes, you're in a mirror image universe with reversed handedness, so the sign of the angle needs to change too. That means negating `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, giving the final result:

`X, -Y, -Z, W`

[I've shown these steps in a few prior answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39518+quaternion+handedness), so remember to do a search first to find solutions even faster than writing a post and waiting for a reply.